# Correlation coefficient of a product

Tags: statistics, correlation

A simple basic question, but I can't think of a satisfying answer... I wonder if there is an intuitive explanation why this is not true

cor(X*A, Y) = cor(X, Y/A)

when A is a vector and the multiplication is elementwise?